# I need to resize the images in my project react + gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

My application web its so slow, i need to improve for what i going to resize the size of my images.

i should to resize the images before to upload? or should i use this plugin gatsby-plugin-image (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/)?

> gatsby-plugin-image
>
> Adding responsive images to your site while maintaining high
> performance scores can be difficult to do manually. The Gatsby Image
> plugin handles the hard parts of producing images in multiple sizes
> and formats for you!

what is better?
if i choose the first one option my code will be like this: with this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-file-resizer

```
const resizeFile = (file) => new Promise(resolve => {
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(file, 300, 300, 'JPEG', 100, 0,
    uri => {
      resolve(uri);
    }, 'base64' );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend on where are you using [`react-image-file-resizer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-file-resizer) package. For what is worth, I would say that is not worth it at all. Gatsby handles the image treatment/resizing/transforming process during the build process using some Python-based code, which runs in the server directly (not in the front-end like the library you've shared) so the performance won't be affected. Of course, this can increase the build time, but doesn't affect the PageSpeed Insights score, in fact, otherwise, because of that performance, you images will be optimized as soon as they are served, unlike `react-image-file-resizer`, where it's React-based code that triggers all the image treatment.

That said, your image optimization should be done by your queries (where you fetch those images), taking fluid or fixed sizes (in v2) or `StaticImage` or `GatsbyImage` (in v3), lifted with the needed sizes to serve the images that you need in each device because Gatsby will serve the image sizes that you are telling to, so if you need some treatment should be done there.

Comment: My images are being stored in firebase, should I use graphql too, is it possible to use this plugin with firebase? I ask another question for that question?

Comment: I'm not sure about your detailed specs. If your images are stored in Firebase, you should need to fetch them, download them and allow Gatsby to treat and optimize them (Maybe this helps you https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-firestore/ and https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-firebase-collections/)

Comment: then shouldn't i use this plugin gatsby-plugin-image/)?

Comment: Yes of course, you need them all `gatsby-plugin-image` will create the GraphQL nodes that you'll use to display your images. But first you need to get those images.

Comment: algolia is in charge of obtaining the images from firebase, I ask the algolia to list it in the frontend in a list

Comment: As you may guess, it's impossible for me to know these implementation details if you've never mentioned them before... If Algolia's get your images, you have no access to them. You should use the queries (with the proper image size) before submitting them

Comment: what Queries should I do before upload the images?

Comment: The ones that generate the sizes of the images that you'll need to consume before, and depending on your Gatsby version: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/#fixed-queries or https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/#dynamic-images

Comment: Where should I put those queries, sorry that I asked you many times but I can't create another question because of my reputation

Comment: In the file where you send your data to Algolia https://github.com/algolia/gatsby-plugin-algolia